# How to deal with a user who has figured out how to bypass the serial down voting algorithm

Tags: discussion, support

Someone out there has nothing better to do than to get up every morning and downvote my old posts after the initial serial downvoting they initially did was reversed by the auto detection algorithm. I've read to flag a post and have done so but this is extremely annoying. I help people out whenever I can and people help me out when I can't find answers and that's what makes this site great. I don't want to delete unanswered questions or ones others will find useful just to stop their pathetic hatred of me for something I did or didn't do that made them upset.

I realize some moderators don't have the time to address these disruptive individuals in a peer supported website. But really, they should be banned at least for some period to keep the site working as a knowledge transfer site.

If anyone has some good ideas for dealing with this type of disruptive behavior that has not been answered in prior posts I'd like to hear about it. I've just been answering or asking good questions to keep their deviant behavior in check but there has to be some other ways around it.

Comment: Given that you've *already* flagged a moderator, you've already done what you can, you just need to wait for it to be handled.  There isn't anything for us to do at this point.

Comment: Just to let you know, you weren't the only one impacted by this person. When it was clear that they were doing this after the last round of downvotes had been invalidated, I passed this along to the SE team to invalidate the latest round of this. The person responsible has been dealt with, and won't be able to downvote anyone for a little while. These votes should be invalidated reasonably soon. Sorry you had to deal with this.